# EF Core query that will translate to TRY_PARSE or similar

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I query a table using EF Core that has a `Value` column for user-defined fields that is of type `nvarchar`, since users can put whatever they want into it.

I need a way to query this table and look for rows where `Value` is numeric and within a given range. For example, the SQL query would look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [MyTable] AS [t]
WHERE TRY_PARSE([t].[Value] AS money) > 100
```

If I do an EF Query like this:

```
dbContext.MyTable.Where(t => Convert.ToDecimal(t.Value) > 100)
```

It will use this SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM [MyTable] AS [t]
WHERE CONVERT(decimal(18, 2), [t].[Value]) > 100.0
```

Which fails for `Value` columns containing strings that cannot be parsed. I know these are SQL Server specific functions, and I cannot use `out` variable declarations in an expression, so I'm wondering if this is even possible? I'm really trying to avoid pulling everything into memory and doing the query there.

Comment: A straightforward solution would be to use a raw SQL query upon the EF Core context. You can find more information [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql)

Comment: [This](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5311184/EF-Core-3-x-support-for-SQL-Servers-TRY-PARSE-func) looks promising. It uses EF Core's native function-mapping facilities.

Comment: @madreflection I was hoping not to need a 3rd party package but I suspect if what I want was possible already he wouldn't have gone through the trouble of creating the library, so that's probably my best option.

Comment: We use third-party packages more often than we might realize (Newtonsoft.Json, anyone?). What I would argue you should be more concerned about is the amount of "hackery" (tech debt) involved, and this one has none\* since it's using function mapping and EF's own expression tree types to generate the SQL. That's about as tech-debt-free as you're going to get for something like this. If you're still concerned, fork the repo.

Comment: \*none that I can see, although I still want to analyze for any potential "gotchas" in the type expressions, i.e. the part after `AS`.

Comment: In database design a column should have a single type. But if you really need to serialize a type to nvarchar you could store the type in another column and use it to filter out convertable rows.